# How to make skimage slic return desired number of segments?

Tags: python, image-segmentation

I am using skimage implementation of slic

```
segments = slic(img, n_segments=10)
```

I execute this for the entire test set of MNIST in order to get Superpixel, 10000 images.

[image]

I have checked how many different segments were produced by slic this varies from 2 to 7, however it never got segmented into 10 segments as I have set in the parameter.

```
all_segments = []
for batch_idx, (example_data, example_targets) in enumerate(test_loader):
    segments = slic(example_data.squeeze(), n_segments=10)
    all_segments.append(segments)

print(min([np.max(x) for x in all_segments]))
print(max([np.max(x) for x in all_segments]))
```

How can I force slic to return desired number of segments?